# What does Islam say about a male who is excessively wealthy but refuses polygamy?

Tags: polygamy

Out of curiosity, what does Islam say about a male who is excessively wealthy but refuses polygamy.

Is such a person considered selfish?

Comment: Your question gives the impression that you think polygamy is obligatory or a prefered act, have I got the wrong impression?

Comment: You're right, I've been told a scary thing, that polygamy is obligatory if you are wealthy...  I'm hoping I have been informed falsely..

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with a man refusing polygamy regardless of wealth. His wealth should be made accessible to the Muslim community through zakat and charity (sadaqa), not at all required to be by marriage. Also, it should be noted that polygamy is not required in Islam. On the contrary, the requirements for marriage to multiple spouses are such — requiring strict equitability — that such multiple marriages may be more problematic than beneficial. Also if one resides in a country where polygamy is prohibited, one should act in accordance with the laws of the land/ nation in which one resides.

The main purpose of allowing up to 4 wives is social and not religious (relevant to one's belief); it may help provide for and protect women who would otherwise be unmarried and vulnerable. In societies which enforce monogamy, usually women are more likely to be allowed to work, making them less vulnerable economically, and also are given in some cases more overall protection in civilized countries at peace. These are to a large extent personal considerations, and the actual concerns of both the communities and the women in particular should be considered rather than impose some kind of imperative. It is in the Quran associated in particular with being a way to support female orphans and servants or slaves. Hopefully Muslims by now understand that slavery is not acceptable, but that Allah put voluntary ways in place to phase it out rather than the potential disruption of a sudden prohibition.